# Can we use RapidMiner Text Processing plugin for drawing co-authorship networks?

Tags: rapidminer

I'm wondering if we can use the text processing plugin of RapidMiner to create co-authorship networks like ones we can get from Pajek. If yes, please tell me how.

Thanks,